# Why is browser detection on server side inconsistent?

Tags: asp.net, iis, browser

I have a ASP.net web app deployed on IIS.  When I access it using IE8 *locally*, the browser is correctly detected as IE8 through the `request.browser`

If I access the *same* web app with IE8 but this time remotely from another machine, the `request.browser` reports the browser to be IE7 ?!

I have been spinning my wheels with this, do you know why this is happening or how to correct it?

**Edit:**
*No, compability* mode is not turned on on any of the instances. I double checked.

Here are the strings reported to the server in the two scenarios:

Accessed Remotely:

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)`

Accessed Locally:

`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0)`

Comment: Maybe the IE on the remote machine has Compatibility mode turned on?

Comment: Ha! + oned for cracking the mystery. Don't we all just love IE.

Answer (score 1):

Yea it turns out it WAS the Compatibility mode (Thanks Šime Vidas).

Except I didn't explicitly turn it on, and IE didn't make that obvious to me.

By default after installing a fresh copy of IE8, it has the option `Display intranet sites in Compatibility View` ***ON***.   And because I was testing within my network, this option was taking effect.  sneaky...

In Tools --> Compatibility view Settings, un-check 'Display intranet sites in Compatibility View'

[image]

Comment: interesting that localhost wasn't included in intranet, or was the checkbox already unchecked for the local machine IE?